# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException

Tags: android, json

how i can take field from a response of my Get request

this is my response

i want to parser request get and get value of "referentiel"
    this is my code

Response:

```
{
"status": "livre",
"referentiel": "000001498675",
"digitalid": "00004328",
"nom": "SAMI IDRISS",
"date": "10/04/2018 00:00:00",
"email": "",
"mobile": "123456789",
"Compte_principale": "0821006348788",
"Login": "Sami"
}
```

i want to parser request get and get value of "referentiel"
this is my code

enter code here:

```
  URL url = new URL(url1);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while(line != null){
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            data = data + line;
        }

        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for(int i =0 ;i <JA.length(); i++){
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            singleParsed = (String) JO.get("referentiel");




            dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed +"\n" ;


        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


       // }
```

help me please

Comment: There is no array object inside `JSON` at least not in part that you provided

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your `data` response is not an Array of objects but a single object. So instead of using `JSONArray` you need to directly access key of `JSONObject`.

You current code:

```
JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);
        for(int i =0 ;i <JA.length(); i++){
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            singleParsed = (String) JO.get("referentiel");
            dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed +"\n" ;
```

Change to:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    singleParsed = (String) jsonObject.get("referentiel");
    dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed +"\n" ;
```

It will work.